# is there anyway to send notification of new Post is published in wordpress to another page of same website?

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress plugin in which i want that if new post is published the notification gone on another page of same wordpress website.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways todo this. But I would do it this way.

When you create a post, you add a post_meta to that post that tells that this page is new.
Then you have an cronjob or something that is running an wp_query that are searching for all posts that have that post_meta. And when it finds the new post/posts it either clear that post_meta or set it to false.

And then on the page that you wanted to display it somehow, use that cronwork to update that page or something like it.

Hard to describe more when I don't know what that other page should do with the information about the new post